# How to create array based on neighbor specific key on array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Below is my sample array. how to get a neighbor array. check neighbor array and if next array has one item and `key = 4`. add that value into prev array

```
$data = array(
  array('so','item 1','details 1','date 1','qty 1'),
  array('so','item 2','details 2','date 2','qty 2'),
  array(4 => 'details of 22'),
  array('so','item 3','details 3','date 2','qty 3'),
  array(4 => 'details of 33'),
);
```

I am expecting this result:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => so
            [1] => item 1
            [2] => details 1
            [3] => date 1
            [4] => qty 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => so
            [1] => item 2
            [2] => details 2
            [3] => date 2
            [4] => qty 2
            [D] => details of 22 // added
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => so
            [1] => item 3
            [2] => details 3
            [3] => date 2
            [4] => qty 3
            [D] => details of 33// added
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate array using `foreach` and in loop check value of items. If item has one key equal to `4` add value of it to previous item.

```
$newData = [];
foreach($data as $key=>$item){
    if (count($item) == 1 && isset($item[4]))
        $newData[$key-1]['D'] = $item[4];
    else
        $newData[$key] = $item;
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/updMN)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<?php

$data = array(
  array('so','item 1','details 1','date 1','qty 1'),
  array('so','item 2','details 2','date 2','qty 2'),
  array(4 => 'details of 22'),
  array('so','item 3','details 3','date 2','qty 3'),
  array(4 => 'details of 33'),
  );

foreach ($data as $key => $items)
{
    $total_items = count($items);

    if ($total_items == "1" && $items[4])
    {
        $previous_array_key = $key - 1;

        $new_data[$previous_array_key]['D'] = $items[4];
    }
    else
    {
        $new_data[$key] = $items;
    }
}

print_r($new_data);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can walk over the array to get your expected result,

```
$res = [];
array_walk($data, function ($val, $key) use (&$res) {
    if (empty($val[0]) && !empty($val[4])) { // checking if first and forth index to merge array
        $res[count($res) - 1]['D'] = array_shift($val);
    } else {
        $res[] = $val;
    }
});
print_r($res);
```

[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array
[array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) — Shift an element off the beginning of array

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => so
            [1] => item 1
            [2] => details 1
            [3] => date 1
            [4] => qty 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => so
            [1] => item 2
            [2] => details 2
            [3] => date 2
            [4] => qty 2
            [D] => details of 22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => so
            [1] => item 3
            [2] => details 3
            [3] => date 2
            [4] => qty 3
            [D] => details of 33
        )

)
```

([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ab9ca460a7bb471528e96abb553bb5f61a97653))